# Sort LIs in different ULs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, html-lists

I have this markup dinamically generated through PHP/MySQL

```
<div id="sortable">
    <h3>Italy</h3>
    <ul>
        <li id="row_1">Record > 1</li>
        <li id="row_2">Record > 2</li>
        <li id="row_3">Record > 3</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Europe</h3>
    <ul>
        <li id="row_4">Record > 4</li>
        <li id="row_5">Record > 5</li>
        <li id="row_6">Record > 6</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>World</h3>
    <ul>
        <li id="row_7">Record > 7</li>
        <li id="row_9">Record > 9</li>
        <li id="row_8">Record > 8</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="response"></div>
```

I can drag the LIs with jQuery UI sortable to new positions, and get their new order with "serialize", ready for database update
As you can see, there are 3 ULs, but their N LIs are all related so I get a N-items "serialization" with each drag, and that's exactly what I want

So, ie, if I move Record 3 in Record 1 place, I get this:

> 3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,9 < this is just what I want

and not this:

> 3,2,1 < this is NOT what I want

This is my jQuery code:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    items: 'li',
    opacity: 0.6,
    cursor: 'move',
    update: function() {
    var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&nAction=move';
    $.post("mypage.php", order, function(response){
        $("#response").html(response);
    });
}
}).disableSelection();
```

It's working, but not as I'd like: I mean that I need to drag/drop only LIs within their respective UL, and NOT from one UL to another (always retaining the N-items serialization)

In other words, I'd like to be able to sort records 1, 2 and 3 among them, 4, 5 and 6 among them and 7,8,9 among them, without mixing (i.e., record 1 can't go in group 4,5,6 nor in group 7,8,9)

Of course, always getting the N-items serialization! (and that's the main reason why I applied "sortable" to a container dive and then specified LI items)

I tried with "containment: 'parent'", but it works only for the first drag/drop

Here are two online examples made with jsFiddle:

1. [The original one](http://jsfiddle.net/zAUT3/), with LIs going from one UL to the other
2. [The version with "containment"](http://jsfiddle.net/zAUT3/1/), that works only on the first drag but it's a mess in the following drags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zAUT3/2/  - apply sortable to each individual `ul` separately.  Then, whenever you need to serialize, just use `each()` to loop over all the sortables, and build up a composite serialization.

---

Here's the modified code from the jsFiddle linked above:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    items: 'li',
    opacity: 0.6,
    cursor: 'move',
    update: function() {
        var order ='';
        $('#allGroups .sortable').each(function(i,el) {
            order += $(el).sortable("serialize") +'&';
        });
        order += 'nAction=move';

        alert(order);
        $.post("/echo/html/", order, function(response) {
            $("#response").html(response);
        });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Thanks Lee, this works perfectly and you just saved my Sunday! :-)

Comment: @Ivan: glad I could help - have a nice Sunday!